# Swift: Who can help to find out the reason in the code that causes memory leak

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, swift2, automatic-ref-counting

I'm making a demo, but I find that the memory increase when I take photo from camera. So there must be something cause memory leak. How can I inspect where is it?

Here is the sample code I wrote:

[https://github.com/AarioAi/NotesOpen/tree/master/Swift/10.1.1%20Photo%20-%20Avatar](https://www.facebook.com/AarioAi/videos/vb.100011236983846/179251062459459/?type=2&theater)

---

Here's the effect video:

https://www.facebook.com/AarioAi/videos/vb.100011236983846/179251062459459/?type=2&theater

Comment: What makes you think that the instance is not deallocated? (And don't try it in a Playground!)

Comment: @MartinR why not? see my 'answer'

Comment: @user3441734: There were some memory management issues in a Playground, but you are right, this works in a Playground as well. – But then the question is unclear.

Comment: I post an image that the Counsel::deinit() is not working....

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Even with your code from the screenshot, deinit is called, and "Counsel::deinit()" is printed.

Comment: Is there something wrong with my xcode? Or as my friend saying, it's a problem of my personality instead of the code? Oops.... -_#

Comment: Look at your deinit method again: YOU DON'T PRINT ANYTHING! – Voting to close as off-topic: The problem cannot be reproduced.

Comment: OMG, I AM SUCH STUPID.... TXS ^_^

Answer (score 1):

```
class Counsel {
    let bias:String = "Bias"
    var scale: Void -> String? = {
        return "Scale bias"
    }
    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }
}

do {
    var counsel:Counsel? = Counsel()
    counsel = nil
}
```

it prints deinit in playground as expected. to see, where deinit is called

```
class Counsel {
    let bias:String = "Bias"
    var scale: Void -> String? = {
        return "Scale bias"
    }
    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }
}

do {
    var counsel:Counsel? = Counsel()
    counsel = nil
    print("still in scope")
}

/*
deinit
still in scope
*/
```

Comment: Why the Counsel::deinit() not work in my xcode?

Comment: @AarioAi as Martin sad, i am also not able to reproduce your trouble

Comment: I take a full screenshot... Is it because the xcode compiler?

Comment: @AarioAi i don't see any print in your deinit

Comment: OMG, I AM SUCH STUPID.... TXS ^_^

Comment: @AarioAi it is nothing unusual, it could happen to everybody ...